# Unable to post from bootstrap modal

Tags: node.js, post, bootstrap-modal, forms, http-post

In the header of my app, I have a link, clicking on which opens up the bootstrap popup modal. When I insert data in the text boxes and click on Submit, No action is happening. Please advice. Thanks.

Here is my html for the modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
     <form action="addCard" method="post" id="addcard" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
     <div class="modal-body" style="height: 140px;">
       <div class="form-group" style="height: 30px;">
            <label for="title" class="col-md-3 control-label">Title</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Enter Card title here...">
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group" style="height: 30px;">
            <label for="title" class="col-md-3 control-label">Description</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="desc" placeholder="Enter Card description here...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="priority" class="col-md-3 control-label">Priority</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
               <select name="priority" class="form-control">
                <option value="critical">Critical</option>
                <option value="high">High</option>
                <option value="normal">Normal</option>
                <option value="low">Low</option>
                </select>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
       </form>
   </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I have this line in my app.js file:

```
app.post('/addCard', routes.addCard);
```

Index.js:

```
 exports.addCard = function (req,res)
  {
 res.render('index'); 
  }
```